# Vue component interop with vanilla code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to fit [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) inside an existing project that doesn't use Vue. But I could not find any resource or documentation on how I can write a Vue component that have an API that can be used by code outside of the Vue world. Everything is focused on apps built with Vue from top to bottom.

```js
var MyV = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div>
        <h4>{{ message }}</h4>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in items">
                {{item}}
                <button v-on:click="remove(item)">-</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button v-on:click="add">add</button>
    </div>
    `,
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
      items: ['foo', 'bar'],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.items.push(Math.random());
    },
    remove(item) {
      this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
  }
});

var v = new MyV({
  el: c1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.8/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="c1"></div>
```

What I already figured out just by playing around:

From outside of Vue, I can just mutate the `v` instance and the view changes according.

```
// everything works
v.message = "Hi there!";
v.items.push('hello');
v.items.add();
```

How I'm I supposed to listen to a "**onchange**" event? I can se a few ways of implementing this, but there's an "official" way?

Setting stuff is pretty straightforward, I can just set any property, or initialize it while instantiating, but how do I can get data back from this view?

---

Let's say I'm building a dropdown menu with Vue, I can populate this "component" just by setting a property.

If there's like a "submit" button inside this view, how I can notify the code outside of the view the user clicked on it?

If the view provides UI for the user modify its internal state (this.data) how code outside can be notified that the data has been modified, and it can then get the content of it again?

Comment: What change do you want to listen for, and what is going to listen?

Comment: I removed the Backbone tag and you should just remove any references to Backbone from your question since it's unrelated. You're asking about Vue.js and _change_ events, only focus on that.

Comment: When you say listen for changes, do you mean *outside* of Vue? As in Vue notifies some external code about a change?

Comment: Exactly, I'm not building an app with vue just part of it, so I need to make it "talk" with other code.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I edited my question

Answer (score 4):

In the same way that you can call `v.add()` from outside the Vue code, you can `watch` value members from outside:

```
v.$watch('items', (newValue) => { console.log("Items changed!", newValue); });
```

You could also use `v.$emit` and `v.$on` to send and receive custom events, since every Vue instance is an event bus.

Comment: that is very enlightening, very similar to backbone views, that also have a `view.on` and `view.trigger`. do you think this is a good way to interface with a component?

Comment: That's what those tools are there for.